# error: 'vector' does not name a type / error: expected ',' or '...' before '<' token / error: 'vector' has not been declared

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, ubuntu, vector

I am using Qt Creator on Ubuntu 15.04. I just installed OpenCV 3.0 using the script provided on the documentation website (here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV). When compiling my code i get some errors (not present before running the script):

> /usr/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:432: error: 'vector' does not name a type
>    CV_EXPORTS void merge(const vector& src, GpuMat& dst, Stream& stream = Stream::Null());
>
> /usr/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:432: error: expected ',' or '...' before '<' token [..]
>
> /usr/include/opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp:438: error: 'vector' has not been declared [..]

All the errors are listed to be in 'gpu.hpp' besides the first one which is:

> /[..]/main.cpp:6: In file included from ../[..]/main.cpp:6:0:

referring to the line in which I put the opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp include.

I searched Stackoverflow a lot and moved 'using namespace std' before the includes but this just changes the error type (they all turn to

> error: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::zeros(int, int, int)'

or something similar).

The includes I put at the top of the code are:

- iostream
- stdio.h
- opencv2/opencv.hpp, opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h, opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h, opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp,  opencv2/core/core.hpp
- vector
- math.h
- cmath
- list
- fstream
- string
- iomanip

+

> using namespace std;
>
> using namespace cv;

My .pro project file is:

> QT       += core gui
>
> greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
>
> TARGET = FinalMultimedia
>
> TEMPLATE = app
>
> LIBS += -lopencv_core
>
> LIBS += -lopencv_imgproc
>
> LIBS += -lopencv_highgui
>
> SOURCES += main.cpp\

Running the Makefile (make VERBOSE=1) I get:

> g++ -c -m64 -pipe -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../try -I. -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -o main.o ../try/main.cpp

in which opencv libraries do not appear at all (dunno why). I am using gcc/g++ having just run update/upgrade so I guess it'll be 5.1.1. I am a complete Linux beginner, so I'm trying to figure it out. Any help? thank you very much.

UPDATE:

I tried to create a new Eclipse project with the same code inside. I set the right include / libraries (had been using opencv / c++ in ecplipse a while ago). I get the same error. wtf

Comment: post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: In your .pro you end the last 7 lines with '\'. Try '/' for path and '\' as escape character. You say your an Linux, but the paths look like Windows. Maybe link the .so in the LIBS variable, find .so with `pkg-config --libs opencv`. And what m.s. said.

Comment: I am a complete beginner, so I need to ask what does 'link the .so in the LIBS variable' mean.

Running that other command I get:

-L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_video -lopencv_photo -lopencv_ml -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_flann -lopencv_core -lopencv_hal

Comment: Your tags include ubuntu, but your LIB path has a Windows format.  Which is correct?

Comment: I changed my .pro file just now, leaving nothing but:

> LIBS += -lopencv_core
> LIBS += -lopencv_imgproc
> LIBS += -lopencv_highgui

(and QT, TARGET, TEMPLATE, SOURCES of course). Still there are the errors and still the output of VERBOSE=1 does not change. I am using Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: `LIBS += /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so` is what I mean by saying "link the .so in the LIBS variable". You can use all you find, but should only use all that are needed.

Comment: Nothing changes by linking that LIBS (i checked the .so file being in that directory) in the verbose=1 output

Answer (score 1):

Moving the namespace line did solve the compilation problem.  The undefined reference is a linking problem.  Congrats!  That's progress.

Now you just have to determine which opencv lib has that symbol and confirm that your search paths are looking there (They probably are not).  You can use `readelf` to see the symbols inside any particular library.  Your missing symbol probably supposed to be inside opencv_core, but  I don't know that.  You'll have to confirm.  `nm` might help you, too.  Use `man` to see how they work -- both are easy.

You can also track down the make file Qt creates, and use it from the command line.  Add VERBOSE=1 to see every library asked for, and every path spelled out for library searches.

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea how to do this. I changed my .pro lines in:

> LIBS += -lopencv_core
> LIBS += -lopencv_imgproc
> LIBS += -lopencv_highgui
> LIBS += -lopencv_features2d
> LIBS += -lopencv_calib3d

Have I to add another line maybe?

Comment: I updated answer with some detail.  Have you found the file named `Makefile` in your project directory?  I wouldn't try to sift through the contents.  Just `cd` to that directory, then execute `make VERBOSE=1`

Comment: Thanks but I still don't get it. Running Makefile (make VERBOSE=1) I simply get the same errors I'm obtaining inside Qt. I noticed that removing everything inside the .pro file nothing changes. Are just the 'include' lines in main.cpp responsible for opencv libraries?

Comment: Yes, you should get the same errors.  The purpose is to examine the g++ command line.  That verbose output is worth adding to your question.

Comment: g++ -c -m64 -pipe -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../try -I. -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -o main.o ../try/main.cpp

This is what I get

Comment: Notice opencv information did not make it to the g++ command line.  That's the problem.  Next step is figure out why.  I'll look further.

Comment: Hi donjuedo. I found this which seems to explain: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27843066/getting-an-error-when-using-opencv-gpu-on-eclipse-nsight. Do you mind explaining me what i need to do to follow aaron's comment? thanks in advance

Comment: @Paynomindtous, aaron's comments are not quite clear on this.  He did say he solved his problem, and added gpu support.  What is unclear to me is if he omitted the opencv lib that defines your missing symbol (method).  I would think not, but don't know how that gpu lib supports opencv.

Comment: Since you are new to linux, I should tell you about a library convention.  Normally, a linker search for a library named `opencv_core` will actually look for `libopencv_core.so` and not really find it.  Instead, it finds a symbolic link by the same name, and that link points to a file in the same directory named something like, `libopencv_core.1.2.3.so` (with whatever real version you meant).  It is that file which will be used to resolve symbols, like `cv:Mat::zeros( int, int, int )`  You can try to follow the same steps, once the g++ command even knows to look for your lib.

Comment: Sorry didn't quite understand: you're telling me I need to build a symbolic link myself? Pointing what toward what? It's looking for libopencv_core.so and instead finding some other link? I did something similar for the installation of Matlab 2014a unix and mex compiling (guess it's not pertinent at all but at least I guess I can remember which command to use)

Comment: After a successful installation, the link should already be done for you.  Try `locate libopencv_core.so` and that should print the full path of the library.  Next, `cd` into that directory, and do `ls -la | grep opencv` to list all of them.  It should show the link (file) as well as the correct library it points to.  Last, `readelf --symbols thatLibFileName` .You could pipe that lengthy output into grep, searching for "`zeros`".

Comment: Running the 'locate' command I get 'libopencv_core.so' in '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so' and  '/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so'. In the first folder there are 3 different files named 'libopencv_core.so', [..]'.so.2.4', [..]'.so.2.4.9', in the second there are 'libopencv_core.so', [..]'.so.3.0', [..]'.so.3.0.0' files. In what folder do I need to run 'ls -la | grep opencv'?

Comment: That was the right place.  You found them.  I got the placement of the version digits wrong -- sorry about that.  I doubt it confused you, though.  It looks like the 64 bit ones are what you need.  Still, g++ needs to know (on the command line) to look for those libs you specified.  That's the next hurdle to clear, and maybe the only one.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I still hardly get a single word of what you're saying (I mean, in terms of what command to use / what to do). I have removed right now opencv3.0.0 and run `sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev libopencv-dev libqt4-dev`. The error in building the same code changed in `undefined reference to 'cv:imread'` and whatsoever.

Comment: Whew.  OK, it's still a link error, just a different one.  I'm running out of ideas here.  eclipse can use an existing Makefile when creating a project, so if that happened, it would explain getting the same outcome.  Maybe if you delete that Makefile and have Qt Creator build it fresh, it will include the library settings you made.  If not, I'm tapped out.  Good luck!

Comment: I am trying to remove everything by running `sudo find / -name "*opencv*" -exec rm -i {} \;`. Then I'm installing opencv3 again. Let's pray. Than you very much for yr help, much appreciated.