# Vector undefined when using OpenCV nonfree libraries

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I'm using opencv 2.4.8 with the non free libraries from libnonfree-dev. 
Here is my make VERBOSE=1 output:

```
/usr/bin/c++ -DEIGEN_USE_NEW_STDVECTOR -DEIGEN_YES_I_KNOW_SPARSE_MODULE_IS_NOT_STABLE_YET -DFLANN_STATIC -DROSCONSOLE_BACKEND_LOG4CXX -DROS_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=1 -DROS_PACKAGE_NAME=\"test_code\" -Dqh_QHpointer -Wno-deprecated -g -I/opt/ros/indigo/include -I/usr/include/opencv -I/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree -I/usr/include/vtk-5.8 -I/usr/include/pcl-1.7 -I/usr/include/eigen3 -I/usr/include/ni    -Wall -o CMakeFiles/test_code.dir/src/main.cpp.o -c /home/amai/working_workspace/src/test-code/src/main.cpp
```

And when I include  I get this error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp:46:0,
                 from /home/amai/working_workspace/src/test-code/src/ImageProcessing.h:4,
                 from /home/amai/working_workspace/src/test-code/src/ROSUnwrapper.h:13,
                 from /home/amai/working_workspace/src/test-code/src/main.cpp:17:
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:128:28: error: ‘vector’ has not been declared
                     CV_OUT vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints,
                            ^
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:128:34: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
                     CV_OUT vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints,
                                  ^
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:127:10: error: ‘void cv::SURF::operator()(cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, int) const’ cannot be overloaded
     void operator()(InputArray img, InputArray mask,
          ^
In file included from /usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp:46:0,
                 from /home/amai/working_workspace/src/test-code/src/ImageProcessing.h:4,
                 from /home/amai/working_workspace/src/test-code/src/ROSUnwrapper.h:13,
                 from /home/amai/working_workspace/src/test-code/src/main.cpp:17:
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:124:10: error: with ‘void cv::SURF::operator()(cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, int) const’
     void operator()(InputArray img, InputArray mask,
          ^
In file included from /usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp:46:0,
                 from /home/amai/working_workspace/src/test-code/src/ImageProcessing.h:4,
                 from /home/amai/working_workspace/src/test-code/src/ROSUnwrapper.h:13,
                 from /home/amai/working_workspace/src/test-code/src/main.cpp:17:
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:132:5: error: ‘AlgorithmInfo’ does not name a type
     AlgorithmInfo* info() const;
     ^
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:142:40: error: ‘vector’ has not been declared
     void detectImpl( const Mat& image, vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, const Mat& mask=Mat() ) const;
                                        ^
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:142:46: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     void detectImpl( const Mat& image, vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, const Mat& mask=Mat() ) const;
                                              ^
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:143:41: error: ‘vector’ has not been declared
     void computeImpl( const Mat& image, vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, Mat& descriptors ) const;
                                         ^
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:143:47: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
     void computeImpl( const Mat& image, vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, Mat& descriptors ) const;
```

I've tried putting using namespace std; before the includes like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918837/error-vector-does-not-name-a-type-error-expected-or-before-t) solution specified, but it didn't help. I've installed the nonfree libraries and made sure they were linked like many solutions have described, but so far the only thing that has removed the vector related errors is putting the lines:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
```

directly into the include file. However, this does not remove other include problems.

Comment: Either a bug in the libraries you are using or an incorrect setup on your side. The first should be filed with the libnonfree and/or opencv developers, the latter is not known, thus this question seems not resolvable in the given context here. **Try to create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: You should specify what are the "other include problems". Besides, the best way to use Opencv is to build it. [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html) it explains how. Besides, if you don't have old programs using the old OpenCV interface, it is maybe worth to start directly from the latest version, currently OpenCV 3.1 [(Guide here)](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html)

Comment: Thanks. Compiling OpenCV from source fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is caused by installing OpenCV libraries without CUDA support. To fix this, compile OpenCV from source with CUDA.